# Is there an "ApplicativeIO" class?

Tags: haskell, applicative, fam-proposal

Is there somewhere in Hackage a typeclass analogous to [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO) but for `Applicative`s, that allows one to easily lift `IO` actions to ["applicative composition stacks"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html)  based on `IO`?

If such a typeclass existed, would it be made obsolete by the implementation of the [Applicative-Monad Proposal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)? Does the proposal involve a relaxation on the `Monad` constraint for `MonadIO`?

Comment: I think relaxing the `Monad` constraint is worth considering.

Comment: In case people are wondering, the laws would be `liftAIO (pure r) = pure r` and `liftAIO (f <*> x) = liftAIO f <*> liftAIO x`

Comment: I think the answer the question "Is there somewhere in Hackage a typeclass analogous to MonadIO but for Applicatives?" is "No" (I couldn't find anything, at least), but that doesn't mean @GabrielGonzalez won't write a blog post about it at some point.

Comment: Relaxing the `Monad` constraint for `MonadIO` would be problematic if for no other reason than that there is a lot of code out there with type signatures like `(MonadIO m) => ... -> m ...` that requires `m` to be a `Monad` (for reasons unrelated to `liftIO`). But `MonadIO m` is not equivalent to `(Monad m, ApplicativeIO m)` either, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was [a related discussion on haskell-cafe](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-October/110700.html) a year ago. In the [Reddit comments](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1ni8r6/should_it_be_monadio_applicativeio_functorio_or/) I gave [an example](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1ni8r6/should_it_be_monadio_applicativeio_functorio_or/ccjk46z) of a natural transformation (`g`) from IO to another monad that is an applicative functor morphism (i.e., satisfies the laws that Gabriel Gonzalez mentioned) but is not a monad morphism (it does not satisfy the additional law relating to `>>=`). So, even in a world with AMP, `ApplicativeIO m` and `MonadIO m` are really different things, even when `m` is a `Monad`!

In an ideal world you'd have a setup like this:

```
class Functor f => FunctorIO f where
    liftIO :: IO a -> f a
    -- such that liftIO is a natural transformation (automatic, by parametricity)

class (Applicative f, FunctorIO f) => ApplicativeIO f where
    --   ... and liftIO is an applicative functor morphism

class (Monad f, ApplicativeIO f) => MonadIO f where
    --   ... and liftIO is a monad morphism
```

and magical fairies would define `ApplicativeIO` and `MonadIO` instances exactly when the corresponding laws were satisfied.